# MySQL join table twice without duplicating data

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(l1.elapsed)) AS run
FROM pattern
INNER JOIN link l1 ON l1.section = pattern.section
WHERE pattern.service = "44-A-B-y10-1" AND pattern.direction = 'outbound'
```

The above query returns `00:30:00` for the `run` value in the select statement. I now need to add a second reference to the `link` table. I won't bother going into why as it's not directly related to the question.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(l1.elapsed)) AS run
FROM pattern
INNER JOIN link l1 ON l1.section = pattern.section
INNER JOIN link l2 ON l2.section = pattern.section
WHERE pattern.service = "44-A-B-y10-1" AND pattern.direction = 'outbound'
```

Above is the new query. The problem is, I would have expected `run` to still return `00:30:00` as it is only getting the `SUM` of `l1`, but it now returns `32:00:00`. Could someone please explain why this is happening? I need to retain the `00:30:00` value but still join a second copy of the table.

Is this possible?

Schema: http://pastebin.com/0vC9pcqz

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Provide DDL of the tables and some sample data and the expected output. Just by going through the query its hard to say anything.

Comment: I apologise for not providing DDL, I wasn't sure if it would be relevant for this question. I will edit the question momentarily.

Comment: Hmm. SQLFiddle is down - any suggestions?

Comment: To a rough approximation, there is no question appropriate for this tag (mysql) and this site (SO) for which DDLs are inappropriate/irrelevant. We don't need a fiddle (although it's nice). DDLs will suffice.

Comment: @Strawberry I have exported DDL here http://pastebin.com/0vC9pcqz

Comment: I use "DDLs" as a shorthand for CREATE and INSERT statements. I use "desired result set" as shorthand for, well, desired result set!

Comment: Are you sure your join conditions are correct? For me it seems like the rows will multiply.

Comment: @Strawberry How can I create a shorthand CREATE statement when the table is large? The desired result set is already in the question, I need the `run` value to return `00:30:00`.

Comment: @SalmanA Could you explain why you think the rows will multiply in an answer? This is the information I was trying to obtain from the question, I think this is more of a problem with my lack of understanding of the way MySQL joins work

Comment: @jskidd3 see http://pastebin.com/WzhGTWXM (it would return 8 rows instead of 4 based on the join condition).

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery

```
SELECT r1.run AS run 
FROM ( 
    SELECT pattern.section AS section, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(l1.elapsed)) AS run
    FROM pattern
    INNER JOIN link l1 ON l1.section = pattern.section
    GROUP BY pattern.service, pattern.direction, pattern.section
    WHERE pattern.service = "44-A-B-y10-1" AND pattern.direction = 'outbound'
    ) r1
INNER JOIN link l2 ON l2.section = r1.section
```

If You want get only 1 row use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r1.run AS run 
FROM ( 
    SELECT pattern.section AS section, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(l1.elapsed)) AS run
    FROM pattern
    INNER JOIN link l1 ON l1.section = pattern.section
    GROUP BY pattern.service, pattern.direction, pattern.section
    WHERE pattern.service = "44-A-B-y10-1" AND pattern.direction = 'outbound'
    ) r1
INNER JOIN link l2 ON l2.section = r1.section
```